# Accessing one lua instance from multiple C/C++/Java programs

Tags: api, lua, ipc

I have some experience in lua, but now I faced the challenge to which i could have simplest solution, if only statement in topic was possible.

**The problem**

In short, the program (set of programs) are to be connected through lua, forming some sort of IPC. Now, i can create Lua state on each one of them, but then i would still need to use Lua-Lua IPC. I can do it, but i thought that if I could just create one instance, and have access to it from all of these apps, i could simplify the process severely.

Now i am aware of the fact that the central lua app would need to be written in thread-safe way. As first, naive approach I wanted to queue data from all the applications and then use coroutines to resolve the events.

**The question (broke into parts):**

1. Is accesing one Lua state using native API calls possible from more than one 'host'
2. If it is, how can it be done and what i must ensure I do, to be sure it will run correctly.
3. If not, that pretty much conludes the question, because I will try to use Lua IPC, which is pretty google'able.

**Edit 1:**
I'm now digging through different lua "communication" libraries, but really can't find any. Point 3 of the question is now much more valuable, since I'm now stuck on localhost TCP + JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lua is not thread-safe within a `lua_State` (it's safe to use multiple separate `lua_State`s across threads, but not to access the same one in different threads). So even if the API had some inter-process communication stuff, it wouldn't work with more than one process accessing it.

Comment: So i would need to set up one lua state per application. Can you elaborate on memory footprint and perfomance of this approach?

Comment: @Bartek: The "memory footprint and perfomance" would depend on exactly what you're communicating, exactly how much you're communicating, what data you're loading and cross-talking, and a host of other information you haven't provided.

Comment: Communicating a lot (I can't give you exact number), and sending data not specific to lua. As for memory, I am a bit afraid if creating lua state for every application I launch won't be too expensive.

Comment: @Bartek: I think you missed a salient part of what I said, "...would depend on ***exactly*** what..." I can't tell you what would happen without precise knowledge of what you're doing. So unless you're going to provide specific, exact details (and "a lot" is neither), I can't help you with that.